# Why does this nginx regex not work correctly?

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following rewrite:

```
  location ~ ^/home/.+$ {
    rewrite "(.+)$" /home break;
  }
```

However, it causes a redirect loop for some reason when redirecting to `/home`. I have the `.+` to match *more than* one character after the last slash, but it seems to still match with just `/home` or `/home/` on its own.

I tried it on regexpal and seems to work fine. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

What I want to do is redirect the following URL:

`/home/login`

to

`/home/` or `/home`

without changing the URL displayed in the browser.

Comment: /home and /home/ are probably an alias to /home/index.html. You show us too little of your configuration to infer and conclude anything. Moreover, this is probably not the right site to ask this since it's not a programming question

Comment: You probably don't want to use `break`. The `break` causes the rewritten URI to be evaluated within the same `location` block, and by default Nginx will issue an external redirection to `/admin/`. Try using `rewrite...last` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked logs, /home or /home/ is not matching with location tag.